# [[PromisseValue]] React

Tags: javascript, react, get, react-router, async-await

Estou fazendo um get um uma api em NodeJs, só que o resulta está voltando dentro de uma [[PromiseValue]], como faço para acessa-lo diretamente?

Com async e await funciona, mas quando para ele pra fazer a autenticação na pagina de rotas ele nao entende o "true" ou "false"

Função que faz a autenticação:

```
export const isAdmin = () => {

var result = api.get(`/role/listar/${role}`)
console.log(result)
if ("admin" !== "admin") {
    console.log('ola')
    return false

} else {
    console.log("hello")
    return true
}
```

}

Função que confere se o usuário e true ou false:

```
const AdminPrivateRoute = ({ component: Component, ...rest }) => (
      <Route
        {...rest}
        render={props =>
          isAdmin() ? (
            <Component {...props} />
          ) : (
              <Redirect to={{ pathname: "/", state: { from: props.location } }} />
            )
        }
      />
    );
```

Obs: Estou usando o React e o axios.

Comment: "admin" !== "admin" sempre irá retornar false, não?

Comment: Foi só pra colocar no exemplo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
api.get(`/role/listar/${role}`)
  .then(results => {
    console.log(result)
  })
```

ou dependendo da versão do node

```
export const isAdmin = async () => {
  var result = await api.get(`/role/listar/${role}`)
  console.log(result)
}
```

Comment: Mas quando vou usa-lá para verificar se e true ou false, ele não entende por conta do async e await

Comment: @GustavoHenrique não sei se entendi o que vc quis dizer, mas vou mudar o exemplo considerando que a sua API retorna uma string com a role do user

Comment: Sim, minha API retorna um JSON com o role, ai eu faço uma comparação para vê se e admin ou não.

Answer (score 0):

Além do que o Matheus falou, é necessário retornar algum valor da função `isAdmin()`.

Por exemplo, se sua api retorna `true` ou `false` na requisição, basta usar o async/await, armazer o valor em uma váriavel, por exemplo `result` e logo após retornar essa váriavel `return result`.

Desse jeito você pode usar ela `isAdmin()` em um `if` por exemplo, porque ao ser executada, ela retornará um valor `true` ou `false`.